# running matlab script from command prompt not taking all parameters for startup.m

Tags: matlab

I run a script in folder

> C:\SVN\myscripts\tst1.m

with following command on cmd.exe( Win 7)

```
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -minimize -r "tst1"
```

This executes fine. However, as mentioned in the *"help"* document, I can specify multiple scripts/functions like

```
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -minimize -r "tst1, exit"
```

This worked too.

However, if the same is done on ***startup.m*** file( my own file which sets some paths before calling some other Matlab Scripts) that is located as

> C:\SVN\myscripts\StartupScript\startup.m

in following manner( after changing *pwd* to above folder):

```
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -minimize -r "startup, exit"
```

The ***Startup.m*** does execute all its contents sucessfully, but at the end of it, I get following message :

> Undefined function or variable 'startup'.

and Matlab returns the control to command prompt with non zero exit code.

Any reasons for this kind of behavior.
Thanks
sedy

Comment: Are you sure you can specify multiple commands that way? I think you can only specify a single statement to be run (see [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html)). So, try `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin\matlab.exe" -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -minimize -r "tst1, exit"`

Comment: @LuisMendo: That's the answer. `matlab.exe -?` states the same: `[-r MATLAB_command]`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks Luis. It worked but I have updated question.